# Can someone help me to identify the IC marked A105 T44A MUGL 0J2785 in the picture? Is it a kind of liquid sensor?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

It's a 20-pin SMD chip on the right side marked A105 T44A MUGL 0J2785

[image: A105 T44A MUGL 0J2785 SMD COMPONENT 20-pin surface mounted]

Comment: Just FYI, if you look closely, it's a 20-pin package so I've edited the question. Can you add any details in the question about why you are asking about a liquid sensor? What background info do you have, which makes you think that? Also can you explain the function of that PCB, where it comes from and any other context you can add into the question? Where does the wiring from that connector go? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ATTINY44-20MU. The pinout matches the package pretty well (check the DNC pins and VCC on the QFN package)